# Convert From Northing/Eastings to Latitude/Longitude with QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

How can I convert a file with the projection below (NAD83) to one with Latitude and Longitude?

The import file is a SHP file and I would like to export back out a SHP file.

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-114 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

A bit of a beginner with GIS and QGIS but familiar with ArcGIS though I no longer have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the file, the CRS should be assigned automatically. You can check that with Rightclick, `Set CRS for Layer`. If not, create a custom CRS with the proj string you mentioned under `Settings -> Custom CRS`.

Then rightclick on the layer, `Save As ...` under a different file name, `Select CRS` and navigate to a lat/lon CRS from list.

Comment: Thanks, I was forgetting to select the Geographic Coord, not Projected list that was showing by default.